# How can I make my ubuntu 11.10 use less of my memory and processor?

Tags: 11.10, custom-distributions

I have a computer with a Celeron 1.6 GHz processor and 512 MB ​​DDR2 RAM, and I love this distribution of Linux, so I would like to know if there is some way or maybe a program that can make Ubuntu more lighter.

Comment: What do u mean by less of my processor? With your current spec, you will have difficulty in running Ubuntu on your system. try Xubuntu.

Comment: lubuntu (http://lubuntu.net/) is another awesome option, which I am using in a 1.6GHz but 4GB RAM with an ATI GPU, the results anyway aren't too exciting. And I agree to @TheX that improving the CPU will also increase the experience. Anyway, you should be careful with the Desktop manager of your choose, gnome is doing a great work on my old computer and it seems that 1 GB RAM will also do the trick. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

> ## What is Lubuntu?
>
> Lubuntu is a flavor of Ubuntu based on the Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment (LXDE), as its default GUI. The goal is to provide a very lightweight distribution, with all the advantages of the Ubuntu world (repositories, support, etc.). Lubuntu is targeted at "normal" PC and laptop users running on low-spec hardware.

Source: [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Your options are limited... in other words, you need to upgrade your processor...

upgrading your ram might help too but I doubt it.

You could also consider using a lighter Desktop enviroment. such as lxde